# Finding out what caused high response time in Application Insights Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azureportal

I'm seeing a spike in my server response time at a certain time, I want to pinpoint exactly what caused this spike. I wanted to know is there a way I can check which process caused this spike or what led to the high CPU usage that increased the server response time. I'm using Application Insights from the Azure Portal, and wasn't able to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You may turn on and use remote profiling functionality to identify how it happens. [Reference](https://azure.microsoft.com/ru-ru/blog/remote-profiling-support-in-azure-app-service/) and go deeper into the analysis. I think there is no other way to just correlate such events - but you may try to go deeper into the session recorded by the AppInsights and see that using timelines you have from the graphs.